# Upgrade to W10 with official W7 key but non official W8.1 installed

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10-upgrade

Current situation:
PC has an OEM key from Asus for an W7 home edition.
PC at this moment is running W8.1 pro not licensed.

Goal:
Update the PC to W10 without losing any information. That also includes the registery for custom installed software and programs.

Tried 1:
Run the windows 10 usb media tool to upgrade from the unlicensed 8.1 and entered the W7 OEM serial. Not working. Giving a message that the serial is not valid.

Tried 2:
Made a backup of the running W8.1 unlicensed software and then downgraded to windows 7. Stored info to the folder Windows.old. But not all software and registery entries were saved.

Question:
How can I upgrade a non licensed W8.1 pro to windows 10 with a legit W7 home key without losing data??
So no clean install. A real update.

Thanx

Comment: Upgrade to Windows 10, the change the key, to the Windows 7 key using the appropriate command.  When prompted for a key, skip that step, or don't use unlicensed software.

Comment: You can also call the activation center, talk to a human, and just say the license key is being rejected

Comment: You can also backup your installation, install Windows 10 on the HDD, use the Windows 7 license to activate the installation, restore the your installation, then upgrade to Windows 10.  You can also achieve that by, using Hyper-V VM, since the VM will be the same hardware.

Answer (score -1):

After a while I found the solution:

The problem why I could not upgrade to Windows 10 Home with the Windows 7 home Key is because the cracked version of windows 8 was an Pro version.

It seems if you upgrade to windows 10 the installer will always install the same version of Windows 10 as the version that is already installed.

If you have a Windows 7/8 Home...you can upgrade to Windows 10 Home.
If you have a Windows 7/8 Pro...you can only upgrade to the Windows 10 Pro.

So to have a legal version of Windows 10 I had to manipulate the cracked Windows 8 Pro first.

Here is a [link](http://henkhoogendoorn.blogspot.be/2015/06/downgrading-windows-81-from-enterprise.html) of an tutorial about how you can change your version of your Windows without reinstalling it. With this edit in the registery I could change my Windows 8 Pro to Windows 8 Home

My Windows 8 version is now Home but it was still not activated. Even if I tried the setup of windows 10 it gave me the warning that I should first activate my running Windows. Ofcourse I have a legal key...but from Windows 7 Home.

Then the only thing I had to do is Activate My windows 8 Home version with the KMS activator. But be aware, this software is not legal.

Ofcourse in my case I  was just using it to use my real Windows 7 Home serial later.

After installing the Windows 8 KMS activator I could easily upgrade to Windows 10 home. Without entering a serial. But I wanted to keep it legal so I went into Windows 10 activation settings and tried my Windows 7 Home serial again and...IT WORKED !!

I hope anyone never gets in the same situation cause its a mess!
Topic can be closed!!